# Запуск веб сервера на Linux

Tags: linux, веб-сервер

Прошу, расскажите как можно запустить веб сервер на linux?

Comment: Укажите хотя бы какой именно веб-сервер (а лучше начните с мануалов по нему).

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий пока не указан дистрибутив линукс (centos, debian, *ubunty... ) и не указано наименование веб-сервера (nginx, apache, tomcat....)

Comment: @AK дистрибутив debian, насчет веб сервера не знаю(банально не знаю отличий, если не жалко своего времени, расскажите об их отличиях)

Comment: Как правило, веб-сервера сейчас не раздают просто статические файлы, а выполняют код, написанный программистом. И поэтому можно бы ещё задавать вопросы - что у вас за проект будет (и в зависимости от этого рекомендовать веб-сервер), но давайте просто скажем, что самые популярные сервера это apache и nginx - и дадим вам ссылку на [первую попавшуюся статью](https://interface31.ru/tech_it/2015/06/nastraivaem-veb-server-na-baze-apache-v-debian-ubuntu-server.html) о том, как поставить. Будут уточняющие вопросы - вот тогда и поговорим

Comment: @AK Сервер встал и работает хорошо, но есть вопрос, как можно подключится к сайту не через ip, а по домену(Пример не `192.168.255.255`, а `www.domain.com`)

Comment: @AK и как можно сделть сервер с шифрованием(не `http`, а `https`)

Comment: Угу. Раз всё заработало - то я пишу формальный ответ, чтобы закрыть вопрос. А, не пишу - вон уже есть ответ от Александра. А в двух последних комментария у вас опять крупные вопросы и причём разные. Пишите два разных вопроса. В первом вопросе вам надо будет указать, где у вас куплен домен (есть ли панелька управления DNS), во втором наверное нужно будет указать, готовы ли вы купить SSL сертификат или вам хватит бесплатного сертификата от letsencrypt.

Comment: @AK Давайте я сделаю правку и добавлю к этому вопросу, мои предыдущие, сможете ответить?

Comment: Нет, я сторонник того, чтобы топики описывались правилом "одна тема - один вопрос".

Comment: отдельные вопросы следует задавать отдельно (с помощью одноимённой кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы)

Comment: @AK оформите ответ по данному вопросу, я его приму, я знаю что уже ответили, но это не совсем то

Comment: @AK вот вопрос по https https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/880518/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5https-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как и подавляющее большинство демонов, программу, выполняющую функции http-сервера, и установленную из пакета, предназначенного для вашего дистрибутива операционной системы *gnu/linux*, можно запустить с помощью программы (скрипта) `service`.

она должна быть выполнена от имени пользователя *root*:

```
# service имя-демона start
```

`имя-демона` можно уточнить в документации к вышеупомянутому пакету.

Comment: Я бы ещё в нотации системд написал как запускать.

Comment: @donRumata, как systemd запускать знает разве что поттеринг. а для *systemctl* и скрипт *service* служит отличной обёрткой.