# Подключение шифрование(HTTPS) на веб сервере

Tags: apache, debian, https

Каким образом можно добавить веб серверу протокол https, вместо http

PS У меня apache2 под debian. [Запуск веб сервера на Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/880384/213987)

Comment: Нужен сертификат сервера (самоподписанный не очень удобно, поэтому надо либо покупать, либо использовать бесплатный от letsencrypt). Вам какой нужен? Если letsencrypt - то [на хабре статей на эту тему вагон и маленькая тележка](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20letsencrypt%20site%3Ahabr.com&lr=213), я лично писал уже пятым или шестым на эту тему. Важно: сертификат выписывается на определённое доменное имя, так что [вы начали не с того вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/880384/213987), сначала настройте сайт на какое-либо доменное имя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо получить ssl сертификат у поставщика сертификатов. Обычно хостинги дают один сертификат бесплатно. Потом, в зависимости от типа сервера установить его.

Вот пример инструкции по установке от [reg.ru](https://www.reg.ru/support/ssl-sertifikaty/ustanovka-ssl-sertifikata/ustanovka-SSL-sertifikata-na-apache) , все легко гуглится, не знаю зачем спрашивать это здесь. Сначала google, только потом stack. =)

Comment: Ага, только у него ещё домена нет ;) И не всегда просто с нуля в тему входить - так что вопрос имеет право на существование и закрытие.

Comment: @AK Да вы правы, я поспешил с данным вопросом, нужен домен, прошу прощение)